Unable to connect to WSL in VS code
It all started when I converted my normal folder to git repo using git init commands to push the code to my branch repo I created in github.
It was successful and I happily turned off my laptop.
Next day I turned on my laptop to start VS code all of a sudden it didn't start. So I tried in Run as Administrator mode. [No Response]
Restarted the system to check. [No Response]
Uninstalled VS Code which was installed from Microsoft Store.
Again, installed from Microsoft Store.
It opened now, but it's not connecting to WSL.
I got an error saying

Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error:
WebSocket close with status code 1006)
Could not fetch remote environment

then I followed the following things:

Removed wsl server bin and data folder and did wsl --shutdown. [still same error]
Downgraded to lower version of WSL and installed.  [still same error]
Couldn't even uninstall WSL Extension from VS Code, it says "WebSocket close with status code 1006"
Since I thought its WebSocket abnormal close, i thought it could be antivirus issue, uninstalled that one as well.
Started using Windows defender.
uninstalled VS code and downloaded vs code.exe to check
Tried from the link

Still no luck. Can anyone help me whether the issue arises because of using git push? Because I tried to git using no reply email address.
I am not sure whether it is causing the issue, just saying whatever I have tried to narrow down the issue.
